# Il saluto "buon pomeriggio" si usa soltanto in alcune zone d'Italia?

Tags: word-usage

Il saluto "buon pomeriggio" si usa soltanto in alcune zone d'Italia?

Leggendo [questo articolo dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/formule-di-saluto_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) mi sono stupita al vedere che, accanto al saluto "buon pomeriggio", c'è scritto tra parentesi "solo in talune zone". Significa questo che tale saluto si usa soltanto in alcune regioni italiane? Sapreste dirmi in quali zone si usa?

Comment: È sicuramente molto poco usato, almeno al nord est. È sufficentemente comune che non mi suona strano ma non sarebbe la mia prima scelta in nessuna situazione. Tra l'altro lo userei solo per salutare quando me ne sto andando via (al contrario ad esempio dell'inglese *good afternoon* che è un saluto per quando ci si incontra).

Comment: Da Roma, la penso più o meno come Denis, e aggiungo che a me fa pensare per lo più a un saluto da conduttore radiofonico o televisivo.

Comment: Anche in Sicilia è molto poco usato. Già dalle 15:00 si usa usare 'buona sera' come forma di saluto informale

Answer (score 3):

Non so perché la Treccani  dica che "buon pomeriggio" è usato solo in talune zone. Io vengo dal nord però ho viaggiato in tutt'Italia e mi sembra che sia al nord che al sud "buon pomeriggio" non sia usato in comuni conversazioni. Credo che dipenda dal fatto che le persone tendono a pensare alla giornata in termini di giorno e sera o luce e buio. Quindi in un certo senso potremmo dire che "pomeriggio" non è necessario per definire la giornata. Tuttavia, "buon pomeriggio" può essere più comunemente usato in programmi televisivi o radiofonici perché definisce meglio il tempo della giornata. Per tornare alla sua domanda voglio specificare che non sono d'accordo con la definizione della Treccani  poiché ritengo che sia al nord che al sud sia un'espressione presente ma in rare circostanze.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Non so se dalle mie parti si usi molto o poco, ma quello che posso confermare è che io - toscano che abita in Venezia Giulia - lo uso moltissimo. 
E non mi pare che sia considerato strano, anzi molti mi rispondono allo stesso modo. Un'altra cosa che può interessare è la seguente: lo uso soltanto all'arrivo (per esempio quando entro in un negozio o in un ufficio), ma mai alla partenza, quando preferisco dire "arrivederci".

Comment: Trovo normale che la gente risponda usando la stessa espressione, anch'io faccio così. Non ricordo che la gente usasse *Buon pomeriggio* negli anni che ho vissuto a Pisa, ma ero in un ambiente decisamente eterogeneo per cui non vuol dire molto (inoltre parti diverse della Toscana possono benissimo aver usanze diverse)

Answer (score 1):

Purtroppo non ho dati di utilizzo da fornirti, ma in base alla mia esperienza è utilizzato un po' ovunque, solo in modo molto meno frequente di "buongiorno" e "buona sera".

Answer (score 0):

In Emilia Romagna mi pare uso recente, mutuato dalla radio e televisione. Ho più di 60 anni, nei miei primi 40 almeno, non l’ho mai incontrato.
Mi è sempre sembrato un calco dall’inglese.

Answer (score -1):

In Toscana si è sempre usato, infatti quando andai per lavoro in Sicilia per un paio di anni trovavo strano che al tocco dicevano già buona sera.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! "In Toscana si è sempre usato": forse abbiamo qualche citazione di un autore medioevale?

Comment: Sempre in tema di regionalismi, "al tocco", per i non toscani, vuol dire "all'una". :)

Comment: Strano: solo tre anni fa l'addetta alla biglietteria della cappella Brancacci mi salutò con un “buona sera” ed era solo la mezza. Per chi non lo sapesse, la cappella in questione è alla chiesa del Carmine a Firenze (Masaccio e Masolino da Panicale sono gli autori degli affreschi) e la signora in questione era indubitabilmente fiorentina.

Comment: Bellissimi affreschi, @egreg, di cui Vasari disse che furono la "scuola del mondo". Ce ne sono anche alcuni di Filippo Lippi, ma quelli del Masaccio sono senza dubbio i più interessanti.